# How to set Jetty's document root?

Tags: java, jetty

I want my existing folder to be jetty's document root? Where can I set it?

Comment: You should post that as an answer and then, after the required waiting period, accept it so this question appears to others as having an answer that has been "accepted"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update :

Ok Found it. In etc/jetty.xml look for jetty.home

```
<Set name="webAppDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps</Set>
```